# parallelise if else statement using OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

So I have the following code below to parallelise and I was wondering if it is possible to assign separate threads to run if and else statements using OpenMP thereby speeding up the process.

```
for(i=1; i<=NI; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<=NJ; j++) {
        x = rand()/((float)RAND_MAX + 1);

        if(x < 0.5) {
            old[i][j] = 0;
        } else {
            old[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the if-else clauses and use `old[i][j]=1-x<0.5;` or `old[i][j]=x>=0.5`;.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you do that? The code doesn't run both `if` branches, it runs the first one OR the `else` one. Use `omp parallel for` instead to parallelize the loop.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,x) shared(old)
for(i=1; i<=NI; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<=NJ; j++) {
        x = rand()/((float)RAND_MAX + 1);

        if(x < 0.5) {
            old[i][j] = 0;
        } else {
            old[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also declare the `x` and the loop control variables `i` and `j` inside the loop and avoid the `private()` clause in C99. The `i` is private by default anyway but I like to be explicit.

Comment: It's also possible to do this without a conditional branch by using `old[i][j]=1-x<0.5;`

Comment: @Zboson just a style thing. No reason I would correct OP's style of programming in my answer. The generated assembly is identical.

Comment: The assembly is identical? That's interesting (+1). I did not out smart the compiler.

Comment: @Zboson I used godbolt.org http://goo.gl/4VTJGA for a simplified test, your results may vary.